# infobox appearing raw text in wikimedia for the wikicode

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I am test the infobox in locally installed. When I am adding [infobox syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Infobox) it not showing properly, as I think its not getting parsed properly

`wikimedia verion 1.22`

```
     {{My template
       |foo = bar
      }}
```

and appearing like the below

`Template:My template`

[image: wikicode]

[image: Wiki output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[edit]: From the attached screenshot it now seems that the problem is in fact a missing template. The code `{{My template}}` will include the content of `Template:My template`. If no such page exists, the result will look like your screenshot. MediaWiki has no built in templates. You have to create them all yourself (or copy them from e.g. Wikipedia). Please read the [documentation](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aTemplates) on how to use templates.

First: Are you sure that you actually have a template called `Template:Infobox about`? Sorry for asking the obvious, but just to make sure...

If you do have the template where it should be, and it is appearing like raw text, completely unparsed, the most likely cause (judging from similar previous questions) is that you have a space before it in the wiki code.

This will work:

```
{{My template
|foo = bar
}}
```

This will not:

```
  {{My template
  |foo = bar
  }}
```

Comment: no space before the the wiki code , still infobox , appearing like raw. Is I have to make use of some extension.

Comment: Can you post the template as well? I.e. the content of `Template:Infobox about`

Comment: i tried with the sample template posted in your answer. Same no success. I have attached the snap shot

Comment: The fact that the text is red indicates that the template doesn't exist! The code will only work **if you have a template** called ”My template”.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit.

Comment: I updated the answer. `{{My template}}` will include the content of the page `Template:My template`. You need to put something in that page, to be able to include it. (Infoboxes are not something that is built into MediaWiki. You have to create templates for them yourself, possibly copying code from e.g. Wikipedia.)